# How can I hide data in MVC?

Tags: database, model-view-controller, information-hiding

I’m new to MVC and am building a project in [ASP.NET MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC).

In my project I don’t want to delete any saved data from my database, but hide them from the user. I look some giving status to data, but I don’t understand. What is the explanation?

Comment: add a kind of flag like 'visibility' to your data model and use it.

Comment: Can you give me any documentation for research?

Comment: what is the type of database that you are using? Is it MySql?

Comment: I'm using .Net MVC

Comment: Have you any  experience with Sql queries?

Comment: No Im not experienced

Comment: So how do you managed to build your project?

Comment: learn about SQL

Comment: so ill give you an explanation as an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I look some giving status to data"*? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can explain a common way to do it. This is a quick answer using [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server).

Please study SQL first before starting your project. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/) is a good place to learn SQL.

I assume the table name is "MyItems":

1. Add another column to your table
2. Name it as *IsActive* (or whatever you want)
3. Set the data type as *bit*

   [image]
4. You can set either true or false for this column

   [image]
5. Write your SQL *select* query as:

   ```
   Select * from MyItems where IsActive=1
   ```

   This will give you all *IsActive=true* records.

   If you want to get hidden records:

   ```
   Select * from MyItems where IsActive=0
   ```